# Aliens contact teen girl through computer

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, tv, computers

Here is a stumper. I would have seen this movie on TV sometime between 1977 and 1980. It was on our local PBS station late night. My brother and I were allowed to stay up and watch Monty Python, and he came on PBS at around 11:30. This was either on right after it or in place of it one evening.

The movie, and I don't know if it was a full length movie or just an hour-long show, was about a teenage girl who began receiving scrambled broadcasts over her computer. Eventually it cleared up and it was a dark haired teenage boy who was talking to her. She fell for him and made plans to be with him. Her brother tried to stop her.

At the end it was revealed that the boy was an alien and he had either trapped her on his planet or trapped her in the computer.

Comment: Do you remember who your PBS affiliate was?

Comment: Our affiliate was WITF in Harrisburg PA. Their website doesn't list program schedules from the 1970s. This was live action. I am guessing it was produced by another PBS affiliate, just like "Overdrawn at the Memory Bank" was, and shown on the local stations. I honestly do not know if it was black & white or color because I watched it on a black-and-white television.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The movie is the *The Wide World of Mystery* episode [***Alien Lover***](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0072465/)

I was reading "Name that Trauma!" on the Kindertrauma site, and the answer to my question was submitted as a suggestion for a question there.  I love Kate Mulgrew, just didn't recognize her in my mind as the young woman in question. [Made for TV Mayhem review of the movie](http://madefortvmayhem.blogspot.com/2012/07/wide-world-mystery-alien-lover-1975.html)

> Mulgrew is Susan, a pretty but somewhat disturbed teenager who understandably went a little bonkers after her parent’s death. She’s just been released from the sanatorium and her Aunt Marian (Susan Brown) takes her in. However, it looks like Marian’s husband, Mike (Pernell Roberts) is less interested in his niece’s mental health and more concerned with her hefty inheritance. Their son Jude (Steven Earl Tanner) is a boy genius who has gained early entry into college. He’s coming home to greet Susan and he brings along his hottie roommate Richard (Harry Moses) who develops a crush on her. Jude has converted his attic into a makeshift lab where he works on all kinds of electronics. Susan uncovers Jude’s homemade TV and also finds a little man living inside of it. He's handsome, likes poetry and he tells Susan she is beautiful as he attempts to satiate her deep-seated loneliness, but everyone else outside of the television set thinks Susan is one tube short of full frequency.